# Different URLs for downloading and uploading with paperclip on S3 storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, localstack

For local development I am using a localstack Docker Container as AWS Sandbox with this Paperclip configuration:

```rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage:        :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  },
  bucket:         'my-development',
  s3_region:      'localhost-region',
  s3_host_name:   'localhost:4572',
  url:            ':s3_path_url',
}
```

Links for download content are generated correctly and are working:

> http://localhost:4572/my-development/files/downloads/be-fl-che-spezialtiefbau-mischanlage-750_ae0f1c99d8.pdf

But when I want to upload new files I get an *Aws::Errors::NoSuchEndpointError* based on a different URL:

> https://my-development.s3.localhost-region.amazonaws.com/files/downloads/_umschlag-vorlage_c534f5f25e.pdf

I searched and debugged some hours but couldn't find out where this url is generated and why it uses *amazonaws.com* as host.

Any hint where to look at?

Comment: Your `paperclip_defaults` object is initiates `:s3` actually. Your upload always will be focus on s3 at that point.

Comment: Localstack provides a S3 Service too and it works, so it is fine. I just want to change where (on which host) files get uploaded.

Comment: I still do not get, how do u get download content without uploading it [NoSuchEndpointError] ? Nor does your upload content work properly ? And if localstack is development, whats S3 production ?

Comment: I mirrored the "live AWS S3" into the localstack Container with some terminal commands. It got nothing to do with paperclip, ruby nor the AWS Gem. In production I'm using the "real" AWS S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to get it working.

Add explicit endpoint url to configuration

```rb
# config/environments/development.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage:        :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  },
  s3_options:     {
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:4572/my-development',
  },
  bucket:         'my-development',
  s3_region:      'localhost-region',
  s3_host_name:   'localhost:4572',
  url:            ':s3_path_url',
}
```

As the url will be renamed with the bucket name by AWS Gem, the resulting domain will be `my-development.localhost`. I didn't found any other solution yet than to add this subdomain into my `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   my-development.localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
::1             my-development.localhost
```

This is not very clean but works. Maybe I found a better work around later.

Answer (score 0):

This could help others. You can update the aws config in your environment specific config file.

```
Aws.config.update(
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:4572',
    force_path_style: true
  )
```